# Time machine slows to a crawl

Tags: macos, time-machine

When the time machine backup starts, the speed of the backup, as reported by the progress window, seem fine. I have a USB 3 disk and it reports 60GB will be backed up in about an hour. For the first 5 minutes, all goes well, with about 7GB getting backup up.

Then about 5 minutes later, 7.5GB is backed up and the dialog report that it will be 3 hours. After an hour 7.8GB is backed up and it's going to take 13 hours. 1/2 half an hour later 7.8GB is backed up and it's up to 14 hours.

- I have checked my disk using Disk Utility and it reports no problem.
- I repaired permissions
- I stopped the indexing service
- Restarted the computer
- I copied a large directory, about 1 GB in size, several hundred files, onto the backup disk using Finder and the copy took about 30 seconds. This is while the backup is hung.
- Console doesn't report much, but when it slows, it just keeps repeating the same line 'Copied X GB of Y GB. J Items of K Items' over and over

I have actually made several attempts at this, removing the partial backup and trying again, even letting it run overnight. The numbers are different, but I'm getting the same basic result. It hits a certain point, and slows to an imperceptible level. Sometimes at 500Mb, sometimes at 5Gb, now at 7.89Gb (and 16 hour).

I don't think it's the external disk, since it starts with no problems and I can copy files onto it with good speed. I don't think it's the computer's disk, since I have no other performance problems. I have OS X 10.7.5 Lion, all software up to date.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? Thanks.

Comment: It could be the same issue as [lion - How to fix slow Spotlight and Time Machine after upgrading to 10.7.5? - Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65486/how-to-fix-slow-spotlight-and-time-machine-after-upgrading-to-10-7-5).

Comment: @LauriRanta Yes, they seem to be the same issues, but probably not the same cause, as I am not getting that first error message and, although I do see the second error, it was from hours before I started this latest backup. I also have the differences in the files that the top question has, as related in the comments on that answer.

Comment: Well the backup finished, a little late, at 11:00 this morning. I'm afraid I have no idea what the problem was.

Comment: I am using Mountain Lion and have no issues with time machine backups so far.

Comment: "I don't think it's the external disk". Try using and internal disk, separate from the one that's being backed up. I'm going to go on a limb and guess that's where the problem lies. The slow rate is probably due to reading / comparing / writing many small files. The burst for a large file may be acceptable on a USB3 external drive, but for anything else it's still slow and tedious. Perhaps the software is poorly written. If possible, try writing the backup to a faster media and then transfer images of the backup (large files, essentially) to the slow USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

As The Russain "Pax" suggested, it's probably the disk firmware, or some such thing.  USB 3 is faster, yes, but the maximum speed achieved by the disk is whatever maximum speed they saw in testing.  It does NOT mean it is sustainable.  Copying many small files is a pain because it is more "meta-operations" to perform before and after the actual copy operation takes place.  Such an event will certainly cause your drive to slow down.

Even if you are dealing with only large files, hard drives are weird.  Sometimes, the caching firmware on the drive is poorly written, and so when you first plug it in, data can fly by at record speed, but then as the drive continues to be used, it slows down more and more.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was posted a long time ago, for anyone new to macOS or Time Machine backups, I have noticed that the behaviour noted by the OP is typical for Time Machine (I use Time Machine as my primary backup software on several different Mac computers). The initial estimate of the backup is just an estimate -it fluctuates throughout the backup in progress. Especially if this is the first backup (assuming the time machine drive remains attached and is able to initiate on its usual timing each hour, subsequent backups complete far more quickly, only targeting changed files- so you don't notice subsequent backups the way you do the initial backup), the progress may be rapid while backing up many smaller files but the estimate increases in time when it encounters larger files and the progress may even appear to stop for hours at a time. The backup is actually still processing but just not updating the estimate as frequently. When it resumes you see a sudden decrease in the overall estimated time. The point is to have patience and not rely on the reported progress as an indicator of the whether the process is stuck or running. Leave it to continue (overnight or longer if needed) as in my experience it eventually completes (which could be hours or days depending on the amount of data in the initial backup and speed of the attached Time Machine destination backup drive).